# How to ignore exception with HandleErrorAttribute OnException event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I want to manage all of my exceptions in some HandleErrorAttribute class.
but **for some specific exceptions** types i want to ignore or cancel the exceptions handeling
and **just continue with the parent request**..

thanks

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing. When exception filter is called, in some cases, just pass the control over to the intended target controller action method. Any solution to this? The solutions noted don't address this case/behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For those exceptions which are of the specific type or types you wish to ignore, you don´t set the ExceptionHandled flag in true.

By the way, you have to create a custom ErrorHandler. It could be something like this (pseudo code):

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //filterContext.ExceptionHandled = exception_is_of_type_that_must_be_handled;
        //Other code, logging, etc            
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to ignore a specific exception and continue with the action method would be to catch the specific exception in your controller and ignore it there.

E.g.

```
[HandleErrorAttribute]
public ActionResult YourActionMethod()
{
    try
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
    catch (SpecificExceptionToIgnore ex)
    {
        //Do something here with the exception
        //E.g. Simply ignore it, Log it, set some modelstate or tempdata
    }

    //Carry on.
    //All other exceptions will be thrown as normal and
    //will be handled by your 'HandleErrorAttribute' attribute.

    return View();
}
```

HTHs,
Charles